# Laurent expansion of $\frac{2}{(z-1)(3-z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question asks me to find all the possible Laurent series expansions of $$f(z)=\frac{2}{(z-1)(3-z)}$$ about the origin so $$z_0 =0 $$

First I convert $f(z)$ into partial fractions to get $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{3-z}$$

We can see there are three domains

$$D_1: |z|<1$$ $$D_2 :1<|z|<3$$  $$D_3 :|z|>3$$.

I first look at $\frac{1}{z-1}$ and I write it in the form $-(1-z)^{-1}$. By writing in this form I can see that it converges in $D_1$.
By applying the maclaurin series I get $$\sum^\infty_{n=0} z^n$$

How do I get the expression $\frac{1}{z-1}$ in the form so that it converges between $D_2$ and $D_3$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{z-1}=-\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}$$ and $$\frac{1}{3-z}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{3}} = -\frac{z^{-1}}{1-3z^{-1}}$$

Can you see how to get a Laurent series for $\frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}$ so that it converges when $|z|>1$ - that is, when $|z^{-1}|<1$?

Comment: Is it not just using the maclaurin series?

Comment: also how do you now what to write $\frac{1}{z-1}$ in that form? is that a general form it should be in to converge outside the domain?

Comment: Which MacLaurin series? :) For your second question: You need $\frac{1}{1-z}$ to either be a power series of $z$ (for $|z|<1$ or a power series of $|z^{-1}|$ with $|z|>1$.

Comment: @ Well In my notes I have got $\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}[1+\frac{1}{z}+(\frac{1}{z})^2 +...]$

Comment: Are you sure that you need the series at $z=0$ ? What you wrote in your last comment seems to correspond to the expansion for infinitely large values of $z$.

Comment: @claudeleiboici yeah the question specifically states about the origin

Comment: @Aljabra Your notes are wrong. $\frac{1}{z-1}\neq \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}z}$. But the series you gave is correct for $\frac{1}{z-1}$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Look up Laurent series if you've forgotten how they work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Thanks ! I really needed to go back. Cheers :-(

Comment: @thomasandrew I made a mistake,In my notes I had $\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z(1-\frac{1}{z})}=\frac{1}{z}(1-\frac{1}{z})^{-1}$ which then equals that series expansion